# Picture Box only re sizes by half?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

So I am making a project for school and my loading form looks like this:
http://gyazo.com/90238893fbe27ff1ae0cae070e22b7c5

When you hover your mouse over either of the picture boxes it increases the size (so you know you are on it).
I used the following code:

http://gyazo.com/97c957806dd9064ca834a0d40d8de944.png

Now when the size changes it only seems to increase the size from the bottom right hand side. How can I make it all increase?

Answer (score 1):

To make it look as as if it increased in size in all directions, you will have to change the `Top` and `Left` properties of your picture boxes and decrease them. This will move them towards the top-left corner. If you increase the size at the same time, it will look like to picture box is enlarged.

Answer (score 0):

Grab the Bounds() property of the PictureBox and use its Inflate() method.  Store the old bounds in the Tag() so you can restore it again.  Something like...

```
Private Sub PictureBoxClientBack_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBoxClientBack.MouseEnter
    Dim rc As Rectangle = PictureBoxClientBack.Bounds
    PictureBoxClientBack.Tag = rc
    rc.Inflate(2, 2)
    PictureBoxClientBack.Bounds = rc

    rc = PictureBoxClientPic.Bounds
    PictureBoxClientPic.Tag = rc
    rc.Inflate(2, 2)
    PictureBoxClientPic.Bounds = rc
End Sub

Private Sub PictureBoxClientBack_MouseLeave(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBoxClientBack.MouseLeave
    PictureBoxClientBack.Bounds = PictureBoxClientBack.Tag
    PictureBoxClientPic.Bounds = PictureBoxClientPic.Tag
End Sub
```